# Is it nessesary to push shift lock when shifting from Reverse to Drive?

Tags: automatic-transmission, shifting

Is it doing damage to an automatic when you don't push the button as long as you've stopped before changing directions?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! W

Comment: If you are talking about the button that prevents you from moving the gear selector from certain positions to others, then obviously you will have to push it to shift out of those positions. If it doesn't require you to push it to shift, then it is not necessary to do so. You should however be stopped when shifting from Reverse to Drive, although you can achieve some spectacular burnouts if you aren't. :)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you've stopped (the biggest damage culprit), there's no damage to the tranny by just shifting it. If there was going to be an issue, the manufacturer wouldn't allow you to do it in the first place. You cannot just shift from drive to neutral to reverse without pushing the button, but the opposite should be able to happen without issue.